# Can someone please help me with this React start?

Tags: reactjs

I have downloaded some code from Github which uses React.

I get the following error when I run npm start in the terminal.

```
  The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
apples-iMac:redux-code-master apple$ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/apple/Documents/redux-code-master/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/apple/Documents/redux-code-master/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2020-10-23T14_20_03_880Z-debug.log
apples-iMac:redux-code-master apple$
```

Can anyone please tell me how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your files in the redux-code-master folder? It looks like you are missing some file

Comment: have you done `npm i`   ?

Comment: Can you share the repo you downloaded? You may not be in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

From your error log it seems `package.json` file is missing from your project. If it exist and you want to build project for relative path then use

```
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

in your **package.json** file. Find more about building for relative path at [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)